# Custom google analytics reporting

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

Can we add custom variable in google analytics report.

IE: Our URL is as  ?module=global_settings&load_tab=global_settings_tab

Can we set a custom variable "module" and "load_tab" using which we cant to track how many hits on which module in reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via a custom var. [Documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables), a way to [extract url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) I leave as an exercise to you (hint: better do it serverside). If you want to store both module and tab you'd need two variables, which might in the long run be a problem - there are only five custom vars available (maybe you should store both values in one variable). Custom vars come in different "scopes" (see docs), since this is about page tracking you should use page level scope.

A tracking call for such a custom var might look like this:

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                                        // This custom var is set to slot #1 (from five)
      'Path',                                   // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  
      'global_settings/global_settings_tab',    // This value of the custom variable.  
      3                                         // Sets the scope to page-level
]);
```

With Universal Analytics custom vars do not longer exist, they have been replaced by custom dimensions and custom metrics.

But you do not necessarily need a custom var (or custom dimensions), since the url parameters, unless you strip them out explictly in you view settings, will show up in the reports in any case. But those reports won't be particularly beautiful or readable.

To beaufity your reports (if necessary) I'd recommend an advanced filter.

1) Goto view settinsg, new filter , custom, advanced. In the first dropdown select Request Uri as filter field.

2) In the textbox enter  module=(.*)&load_tab=(.*) This is a regular expression that will take the values for your "module" and "load_tab" parameters and store them in a variable.

3) Skip the second filter field.

4) Set "Output to -> constructor" to Request Uri. In the textfield enter /$A1/$A2 - these are the variables that stores the results from Step 2.

So if your url has been "?module=global_settings&load_tab=global_settings_tab" this filter will change it to "/global_settings/global_settings_tab" in the content reports (note that this will break Inpage Analysis, and as always with filtered data you should keep an unfiltered backup profile) - same for any other value of the parameters. That would be more easily readable, and you would not have to waste custom vars (which do not show up in the standard report in any case), so this might be useful

[image]